# Can a Snowflake UDF be used to create MD5 on the fly?

Tags: md5, user-defined-functions, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I was wondering if anyone has an example of creating an MD5 result using an UDF in Snowflake?

Scenario: I want a UDF that can set X columns depending on the source to create an MD5 result. So table A might have 5 columns, table B has 10....and accounting for various data types.

Thanks,

Todd

Comment: [HASH_AGG](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/hash_agg.html) - it is not MD5 but it produces a single hash per list of columns

Answer (score 0):

Snowflake already provided md5 built in fucntion.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/md5.html

```
select md5('Snowflake');

----------------------------------+

         MD5('SNOWFLAKE')         |
----------------------------------+
 edf1439075a83a447fb8b630ddc9c8de |
----------------------------------+
```

Comment: Not exactly what I meant. I want a UDF that can set X columns depending on the source to create an MD5 result. So table A might have 5 columns, table B has 10....and accounting for various data types.

Comment: are you looking  for  requiremtn like md5(concat_ws("||", all columns))

Comment: I am looking to see if a User Defined Function can be created to create MD5 columns on the fly. Since there are different source tables, the columns needed for MD5 vary. 

I am basically wondering if UDF is a viable option and if there is an example. Ideally we do not want to create hundreds of MD5 columns manually.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways you can do the MD5 calculation. But I thought it will be good to understand your use case. I am assuming that you want to use MD5 to validate the data migrated to Snowflake. If that is the case, then MD5 way of checking each row on snowflake may be expensive. A more optimal way of validation will be to identify each column for the table and calculate the MIN, MAX, COUNT, NUMBER OF NULLS, DISTINCT COUNT for each column and validate it with the source. I have created a framework with this approach where I use the 'SHOW COLUMNS' query to get the list if COLUMNS. The framework also allows to skip some columns if required, also filter the number of rows retrieved based on a dynamic criteria. This way of validating the data will be more optimal. It will definitely help to understand your use case better.

**MD5**

Does this work for you

```
create or replace function md5_calc (column_name varchar)
  returns varchar
  LANGUAGE SQL
  AS $$
  select md5(column_name)
  $$;
  
  SELECT EMPLID,md5_calc(EMPLID),EMPNAME,md5_calc(EMPNAME) from employee;
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you but I need to see if an UDF is possible in creating MD5.

Comment: Please see the UDF above

Comment: Thanks I will have to try.

Comment: Sure, please do come back and let us know what worked

Comment: Can the function be altered to account for X columns? 

I have one table where I need 5 columns to form the MD5....then another with say 3.

And, I assume I can do function within function to convert to string if one of the columnds is a decimal or date field from source?

example of one scenario:
 SELECT Name,City, md5_calc(Name, City) from TODD_MD5;

SQL compilation error: error line 1 at position 18 too many arguments for function [MD5_CALC(TODD_MD5.NAME, TODD_MD5.CITY)] expected 1, got 2

Comment: I think there is a better way to do this. Can you try the below   SELECT md5(TO_VARCHAR(ARRAY_CONSTRUCT(empname,salary))) from employee; you may not need a function

Comment: This works well but we need something where we can pull columns dynamically through a information schema using Metadata. 

Is that possible?

Comment: Yes look at 'SHOW CLUMNS'

Comment: My requirements for this question is being refined so let me clarify.

If possible, using Metadata from the information schema, can I "tag" columns to mark them candidates for an MD5 function, then use this metadata to dynamically create MD5 function. 

Basically, trying to avoid hand typing each column for each table we need to create an MD5 for.

Comment: Is passing variables using Metadata from the information schema possible into a UDF function that can create a dynamic MD5?